# LINQ Where statements concatenated with OR

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Normally one can concatenate multiple "Where" statements in a Queryable and the results are filtered by using AND logic between the expressions from the "Where" statements.

How can I concatenate the "Where" statements using OR logic?
Something like:

```
query.OrWhere(t => true).OrWhere(t => false)
```

---

I am trying to conditionally create a query by going through a loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
   switch(i)
   {
      case 0:
      { 
           if (something happens)
           {
                query = query.OrWhere(t => t.columnDependingOnIndex is something);
           }
           break;
      }
      //and so on ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jut use or(||) within one Where statement

```
query.Where(somePredicate || someOtherPredicate)
```

Another way is just using .Union -

```
var q1 = query.Where(somePredicate)
var q2 = query.Where(someOtherPredicate)

var res = q1.Union(q2)
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to write an extension to achieve the above? I would like to chain the statements.

Comment: @user2704, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why are you not satisfied with the proposed suggestions?

Comment: Thank you, I like your suggestion, I was just wondering if there's a way to make an extension in order to chain the "Where" statements by logic OR.

Comment: Logically seems like it not possible to have something like your OrWhere.

Comment: @user2704 Of course you could dynamically add `Union` statements to the query, but that's less efficient (for the database engine) than expanding the query by `or` clauses as in the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `query.Where(t => true || false)`?

Some example code:

```
        var someInts = new List<int>
        {
            1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7
        };

        someInts.Where(i => i == 5 || i == 6);
```

Alternately, you could create a a query object that contains all of the functions that parse down your list (here's some self-contained code:

```
namespace LinqPlayground
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var someInts = new List<int>
            {
                1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7
            };

            var queryObjectPattern = new QueryObjectPattern<int>();
            queryObjectPattern.AddOr(i => i == 5);
            queryObjectPattern.AddOr(i => i == 7);

            var intsThatPassed = queryObjectPattern.GetItemsUsingOrClauses(someInts);
            foreach (var i in intsThatPassed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} passed!", i);    
            }

        }

        public class QueryObjectPattern<T>
        {
            private readonly List<Func<T, bool>> _funcsToApply;

            public QueryObjectPattern()
            {
                _funcsToApply =  new List<Func<T, bool>>();
            }

            public void AddOr(Func<T, bool> orClause)
            {
                _funcsToApply.Add(orClause);
            }

            public IEnumerable<T> GetItemsUsingOrClauses(IEnumerable<T> items)
            {
                var itemsThatPassed = new List<T>();
                foreach (var func in _funcsToApply)
                {
                    itemsThatPassed.AddRange(items.Where(func));
                }
                return itemsThatPassed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. But in a split way.

Comment: this will always have True as the predicate, therefore return the whole IEnumerable (no filtering)

Comment: Yeah but OP didn't give us an actual use case, so I used what he posted in his question...

Comment: @user2704 I posted a more realistic example. Why do you feel the need to split the where statement? It seems like you posted what you want to do instead of what the problem you need to solve is.

Comment: I'm creating a conditional query by iterating a loop and because of that it would be nice to chain "Where" statements with OR logic.

Comment: Hi @user2704, I made an update that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't but you could concatenate both querys and get the distinctResult
it should be as follow

```
        List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();
        var statementOne = Points.Where(d => d.X > 3);
        var statementTwo = Points.Where(d => d.X < 0);
        var queriedPoints = statementOne.Concat(statementTwo).Distinct();
```